# Downsized images in fabricjs are pixelated

Tags: image, resize, fabricjs

When I load an image like the one I've included to say 400 dpi high it becomes very pixelated.  I've looked around and nothing seems to work.  I have a collection of images that a user could put on the canvas and the images are re-sized depending on a scale so I can't re-size them ahead of time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Jody

http://rockofagescanada.com/test33_6287.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 1.4.13 FabricJs support image resize filters.

The resize filter can be used in 2 ways:

> -Static resize on load with fixed scale
>
> -Dynamic resize on scaling the image object by code o by mouse drags.

There are 4 filters implemented as of now:

> -SliceHack , not really a filter but an hack to get smoother resize by resizing 0.5 the image multiple times.
>
> -Hermite filter
>
> -Bilinear filtering
>
> -Lanczos resizing with lobes parameter

Here follow some examples:

1. Static resize at load with Hermite filter, fixed scale

   ```
   var theImage = new fabric.Image(imag, {
       top: 0,
       left: 0
   });
   theImage.filters.push(
                  new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
                           resizeType: 'hermite',
                           scaleX: 0.1,
                           scaleY: 0.1
                          })
                        );
   theImage.applyFilters();
   canvas.add(theImage);
   ```
2. Dynamic resize with Lanczos filter, 2 lobes

   ```
   var theImage = new fabric.Image(imag, {
       top: 0,
       left: 0
   });
   theImage.resizeFilters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
       resizeType: 'lanczos', // typo fixed
       lanczosLobes: 2 // typo fixed
   }));
   canvas.add(theImage);
   ```

Comment: As a heads up, in Fabric 2, you set the resize filter like so: `image.resizeFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.ResizeFilter({type: 'hermite'});` See http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the width to 1500, then below code can be used for rezise. It worked for me. Image looks normal.

```
var scale = 1500 / oImg.getWidth();

var newWidth = oImg.getWidth() * scale;
var newHeight = oImg.getHeight() * scale;

oImg.set({width : newWidth, height : newHeight});
```

Comment: Answer did not address the OP's actual question.